# java.lang.String cannot be cast to moduleapi.interaction.DateOnly

Tags: visual-workflow

[image]

So, when i save as default value ( {!ContattoSelezionato.Data_Nascita__c} ) in a 'Date' variable on the flow and try to print it as a string using 'TEXT(...)' i run into this issue

'*java.lang.String cannot be cast to moduleapi.interaction.DateOnly*'.

I tried a lot of ways to deceive it, but i can't, please anyone can help me?!
Of course 'Data_Nascita__c' is a Date record and i'm sure i'm passing the right date format filled.

Thank's to u all.

this is how i convert. cm.dataNascita = '12/11/2018'

```
Account acct = new Account(
Data_Nascita__c = (Date)date.parse(cm.dataNascita)
); // ---> 2018-11-12
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can add more code to your question. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/231166/edit) your question by adding more details.

Comment: Do u need further info?